# Running Heavy JS Tasks w/React Native

Tags: javascript, performance, react-native

Looking for answers/feedback/suggestions on how to keep a React Native application UI responsive while executing a computationally heavy JS task.

I must perform a parse of JSON string information, which is application setup data.

I have identified this as a culprit that is causing UI jank in my application. After receiving a JSON string in JS (it is a file loaded natively), I must parse through the JSON to build an "in memory db" for the application. Sudo code looks something like this:

```
function parseSetup(jsonString) {
  var json = JSON.parse(jsonString); //This can take up to 100+ms for a 3MB JSON file

  for (let item of json.items) {
    // Do some parsing
    // Instantiate model objects w/json info
    // could take up to 3000ms
  }

  for (let thing of json.things) {
    // Same as above
  }

  for (let parent of json.parents) {
    //Same as above
    for (let child of parent) {
      //Same as above, but note this is a nested for loop
    }
  }
}
```

`parseSetup`, can take up to 5,000+ms (5 seconds). This locks up the JS thread which makes my app appear frozen, as the Native touch events & JS logic are queued up after the parseSetup function. Enter InteractionManager's runAfterInteraction. I have had a bit of success using the runAfterInteraction, but I am basically wrapping every line of code I have with the runAfterInteraction. It feels wrong and it doesn't work quite 100% as some of the functions that become wrapped with runAfterInteraction may take longer than the deadline set by InteractionManagers.setDeadline anyway. So here is what I have ended up with:

```
function parseSetup(jsonString) {
  var json = JSON.parse(jsonString); //This can take up to 100+ms for a 3MB JSON file
  InteractionManager.setDeadline(30);

  for (let item of json.items) {
    InteractionManager.runAfterInteraction(() => someInnerFunc()); //Could take 50ms
    InteractionManager.runAfterInteraction(() => someOtherFunc());
  }

  for (let thing of json.things) {
    InteractionManager.runAfterInteraction(() => someInnerFunc());
    InteractionManager.runAfterInteraction(() => someOtherFunc());
  }

  for (let parent of json.parents) {
    InteractionManager.runAfterInteraction(() => someInnerFunc());
    InteractionManager.runAfterInteraction(() => someOtherFunc());
    for (let child of parent) {
      InteractionManager.runAfterInteraction(() => someInnerFunc());
      InteractionManager.runAfterInteraction(() => someOtherFunc());
    }
  }

  //Do the above for more JSON keys (50+ more)
}
```

Am I understanding correctly that any function that is executed that takes longer than 16.67/ms will block the JS thread?

The penultimate question: is there a better way to go about running a long function like this without locking the JS thread? Thank you

Comment: I just watched a talk from [JSConf 2018](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XyVQfqmx2CI&list=PL37ZVnwpeshGGVeMxXxCxjQZBJq5bqM7b&index=14) talking about using webworkers to solve this issue. Might have a look at what they've done: https://github.com/ampproject/worker-dom

Comment: What did you en up with?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at parallel.js.  To be honest, I have never used it, but it looks promising.  It uses web workers, which are background threads, that don't tie up your main js thread.  You're also going to need to put up something like a Loading component until your download completes.  If I can get a working code, I'll send to you.

https://parallel.js.org/

Comment: I have looked into trying web workers as well, but I found that you cannot access instanced variables across the two threads which ideally I would like to do, not to mention there are issues with building for release such as in react-native-threads. Please let me know if you do get an example working. Thank you

Comment: I actually talked to the main contributor of parallel.js, and they DO NOT RECOMMEND using their library for this purpose.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solution.

1. Use redux and redux-persist. These enable to save javascript object in database. It must solve this problem perfectly.
2. In my idea, mobile app shouldn't run heavy task.
   Build API server, and parse json.
   Mobile app just show parsed json from API server.

Comment: 1. Redux-Persist will not solve my issue of parsing that large JSON object. I have already solved the performance issues of crossing the bridge with large amounts of data.

2. This is an app that must run offline - the JSON object is already in it's simplest form, it's just a lot of data to parse through